# Curl Not working to upload a file on server

Tags: php, curl, yii, hipchat

I am trying to upload a file on sever using Api.And it is successful on localhost it is working fine i can easily upload the file on server.
But when my code goes on server then it is not getting uploaded.I Give the read write permission to the folder from where i am fetching the images or files. 
this is my curl code:

```
 $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        if($api_type == 2){
            //$mm = array("message" => $message);

            $message = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $message);
            $message = '{"message":"'.$message.'"}';

            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'Content-Type: application/json',
            ));
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$message);
        }
        if($api_type == 3 & $attachment != NULL){
            $data = array( 'file' => '@'.self::basePath().'/../user_uploads/hipchat_image/'.$attachment);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: multipart/related',
            ));
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        }
        return curl_exec($c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

Depending on PHP version, this is defaulted to `false` in php 5.5 and `true` in 5.6+ ... so check local and webserver version of PHP.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Ok, wow this took far to long to find. I had to update a legacy system NOT to PHP 7, and this is what broke a script.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

PHP 7 removes this option`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` the `CURLFile` interface must be used to upload files.

You can write code like this

```
$data = array('file'=>new CURLFile('/file/path'));
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php